# How to verify the orthogonal projection formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $B = \{\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2, \vec{b}_3\}$ a orthogonal basis $\in V^3$. 
>   Verify that $\forall\,\vec{u} \in V^3$,
>   $$\vec{u} = \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_1}{\vec{b}_1\cdot\vec{b}_1}\right)\vec{b}_1 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_2}{\vec{b}_2\cdot\vec{b}_2}\right)\vec{b}_2 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_3}{\vec{b}_3\cdot\vec{b}_3}\right)\vec{b}_3$$

I know the concept and how to use it, but I have no ideia how to verify it.

Can anyone please help me to check it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `b_i` to make subscripts, and `\cdot` to make a centered dot. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for other tips.

Comment: Also, do you mean $\vec{u}\in V$?  If $V$ you can't take the dot product of vectors in spaces of different dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me restate your problem as I can make sense of it:

**Let $B = \{\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2, \vec{b}_3\}$ a orthogonal basis $\in V$, a 3-dimensional vector space. Verify that $\forall\,\vec{u} \in $,
$$\vec{u} = \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_1}{\vec{b}_1\cdot\vec{b}_1}\right)\vec{b}_1 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_2}{\vec{b}_2\cdot\vec{b}_2}\right)\vec{b}_2 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_3}{\vec{b}_3\cdot\vec{b}_3}\right)\vec{b}_3$$**

If that is what you meant, then what follows may help you:

Given that $B = \{b_1,b_2, b_3\}$ is a basis, we can write $u$  as a linear combination of the $b_i$'s:
$$u=\lambda_1 b_1+\lambda_2 b_2+\lambda_3 b_3$$
Now we should find tha $\lambda_i$'s. Since this basis is an orthogonal one, $$b_1 \cdot b_2=b_1 \cdot b_3=b_2 \cdot b_3=0$$
So we can find the $\lambda_i$ by computing the inner product of $u$ and $b_i$. For example,
$$u \cdot b_1=(\lambda_1 b_1+\lambda_2 b_2+\lambda_3 b_3)\cdot b_1=\lambda_1b_1\cdot b_1+\lambda_2b_2\cdot b_1+\lambda_3b_3\cdot b_1=\lambda_1b_1\cdot b_1$$
So $$\lambda_1=\frac{u \cdot b_1}{b_1 \cdot b_1}$$

Comment: Thanks Behzad, seeing in this way seems really easy!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

This says the coordinates are the projections to axes.

Hint: Let

$$\vec{u}' = \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_1}{\vec{b}_1\cdot\vec{b}_1}\right)\vec{b}_1 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_2}{\vec{b}_2\cdot\vec{b}_2}\right)\vec{b}_2 + \left(\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{b}_3}{\vec{b}_3\cdot\vec{b}_3}\right)\vec{b}_3.$$

Show $(u,b_i)=(u', b_i)$, then you have $u=u'$.